# How to ignore capitalization BUT return same capitalization as input

Tags: python, string, case

My code intends to identify the first non-repeating string characters, empty strings, repeating strings (i.e. `abba` or `aa`), but it's also meant to treat lower and upper case input as the same character while returning the accurate non-repeating character in it's orignial case input.

```
def first_non_repeat(string):
    order = []
    counts = {}
    for x in string:
        if x in counts and x.islower() == True:
            counts[x] += 1
        else:
            counts[x] = 1 
            order.append(x)
    for x in order:
        if counts[x] == 1:
            return x
    return ''
```

My logic on line 5 was that if I make all letter inputs lowercase, then it would iterate through the string input and not distinguish by case. But as of now, take the input `'sTreSS'`and output  is `'s'` when really I need `'T'`. If the last two `S`'s were lowercase, then it would be `'T'` but I need code flexible enough to handle any case input.

Comment: The point is that `if x in counts` will only be looking for `x` in a case sensitive way.

Comment: right, i want that statement to disregard case when looking for x

Comment: Any news? I posted an alternative regex-based solution below.

Answer (score 0):

When comparing two letters, use lower() to compare the characters in a string. An example would be:

```
string ="aabcC"
count = 0
while count < len(string) - 1:
    if string[count].lower() == string[count + 1].lower():
        print "Characters " + string[count] + " and " + string[count + 1] + " are repeating."
    count += 1
```

Comment: would this be treated as its own for loop? where would this be placed in my script?

Comment: @Mr.Jibz I added a more in-depth example for you

Answer (score 0):

The point is that `x` in `counts` is searched for in a case-insensitive way. You have to implement your own case insensitive Dictionary, or use regular expressions to detect repeating letters:

```
import re
def first_non_repeat(string):
    r = re.compile(r'([a-z])(?=.*\1)', re.I|re.S)
    m = r.search(string)
    while m:
        string = re.sub(m.group(1), '', string, re.I)
        m = r.search(string)
    return string[0]

print(first_non_repeat('sTreSS'))
```

See the [Python demo](http://ideone.com/l5Stt1)

The `([a-z])(?=.*\1)` regex finds any ASCII letter that also appears somewhere ahead (note that `([a-z])` *captures* the char into Group 1 and the `(?=.*\1)` is a lookahead where `\1` matches the same char captured into Group 1 after any 0+ characters matched with `.*` pattern, and `re.S` flag helps support strings with linebreaks).

The `re.sub` will remove all the found letters in a case insensitive way, so we will only get unique characters in the `string` after the `while` block.

Answer (score 0):

Here's little change u can make to your code to make it work.

```
 def first_non_repeat(string):
            order = []
            counts = {}
            for x in string:

                char_to_look = x.lower()   #### convert to lowercase for all operations

                if char_to_look in counts :
                    counts[char_to_look] += 1

                else:
                    counts[char_to_look] = 1 
                    order.append(char_to_look)

           for x in string:   ### search in the string instead or order, character and order will remain the same, except the case. So again do x.lower() to search in count
                if counts[x.lower()] == 1:
                    return x
            return ''1
```